# CA ArcServe r11.1 - have to switch Tape Drive Offline then Online to finish backup

Tags: tape, backup

Ill keep it brief, I have an HP Ultrium 1 in a server currently running CA ArcServe r11.1.

I have 5 daily backup tapes, each of which are new.  3 of the 5 work fine without intervention but 2 of them stop at varying points through the backup asking for a new tape, even though that tape is not full.  The way I have found around this is to switch the tape drive offline for 10 minutes then switch it back online, whilst the backup is still running.

Has anyone ever seen this before? If so, any ideas how to permanently fix this.

If all else fails just some pointers in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced similar issues with new tapes before. I just sent them back and had them replaced. If a tape stuffs up when it's new it's somewhat unlikely to get better and considering they have a warranty there is no reason for you to persevere with them. While modern tapes have excellent long term reliability, it does require those tapes to be perfect when they are put in service.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that sounds bad, is the tape drive under support? if so I'd get it swapped out, it might not fix the problem but at least you'll know you've done it. If you've still got the same problem I'd suggest a new set of tapes I guess.

Comment: It is a completely new set of tapes and has only started happening since the new tapes. unfortunately, the tape drive is out of warranty

Comment: balls, sounds like you might need to mess around with trying to get new tapes - if it's the drive you're in a pickle

Answer (score 0):

Try running an erase job on the tapes before their next use.